# Google App Engine GQL query with parameter

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gql

I am using PHP on google app engine to develop a webpage.

I am using PHP-GDS to work with the datastore(database). I run into this problem when writing a query to retrieve something from datastore.

```
 public function getToyByColumn($qid){
     $obj_store = $this->getStore();
     $arr_toy = $obj_store->fetchOne("SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = @inID",['inID'=>$qid]);
     return $arr_toy;
}
```

When I run the app calling the above function this way:

```
getToyByColumn($_GET["num"]);
```

It does not return anything.

However when I hardcode the value/function:

```
 public function getToyByColumn($qid){
 $obj_store = $this->getStore();
 $arr_toy = $obj_store->fetchOne("SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = 20");
 return $arr_toy;
}
```

I would get the correct information for the entry where column is 20. The column in the datastore is set to be integer type. Did I write my query wrongly?

Comment: id look to see what `$_GET["num"]` is actually getting, because if your query returns the correct data when the value is hardcoded then theres nothing wrong with the query

Comment: Try casting your input parameter to an integer. It's probably being auto-detected as a string value when coming from $_GET